# How to filter a Core Data Fetch Request by the 3rd level relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I need to make a list of Products that is present on my Cart.
So I have this data model:
[image]

My idea is get all products that have a cartItem by the SKU Product to make this "Product List".

**My question is what is the best way to do it?**

I tried to make a fetchRequest to the Product entity and apply this NSPredicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sku.cartItem IN %@", cartItemArray]];
```

Bug I get this error:

> 2013-10-29 15:08:10.860 Prototipo[85766:70b] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to
>   parse the format string "sku.cartItem IN (
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa2820  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa2830  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa2840  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa2850  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa2860  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa2870  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa2880  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa2890  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa28a0  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa28b0  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa28c0  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa28d0  ;
>   data: )",
>       " (entity: CartItem; id: 0x8aa28e0  ;
>   data: )" )"'

Thank you so much.
Appreciate your attention.

––––– X –––––

**EDIT (Solved)**

In order to help someone else and to summarize the solution, it cannot be used the **[NSString stringWithFormat:@...]**, the right way is to use directly [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:**@"...", args**].

And just another tip! If you have the same problem and need to get some data filtered for a n-th level, use the ANY + IN on Predicate:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY sku.cartItem IN %@", cartItemArray];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A predicate use its own formating replacement.
Use:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY sku.cartItem IN %@", cartItemArray];
```

Comment: Thank you @dan-shelly! I replaced but now I have another error: "unimplemented SQL generation for predicate". Maybe is not that best way to filter the products?

Comment: BTW I tryed to invert: "%@ IN sku.cartItem" but now I got this error: '-[__NSArrayM longLongValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d3a7d0'

Comment: I've edited my answer (forgot to add the 'ANY' keyword for the to-many relationship)